# How to access and update an already existing tables of sqlite database file in another python file

Tags: database, sqlite, database-connection

I wrote the following code to create a database file and then created a table in that database and inserted values using sql queries in python.
let say this is a file named info.py

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_file.db', timeout=20)
c = conn.cursor()

#Creating a new SQLite table with 1 column
c.execute('CREATE TABLE STUDENTS_ (Name CHAR, RollNo INTEGER)')

a=['Richa', 'Swapnil', 'Jahanavi', 'Shivam', 'Mehul']
b=[122, 143, 102, 186, 110]
p=0

for r in b:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENTS_ VALUES (?,?);", (a[p],b[p]))     
    p=p+1
```

It runs well and gives the expected result.
Now I want to update the same table named STUDENTS_, through another code in a different python file,I tried the code below. 
This is another file named info_add.py

```
    import sqlite3

    sqlite_file = 'my_first_db.sqlite'    # name of the sqlite database file
    STUD = 'STUDENTS_'  # name of the table to be created

    conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_file.db', timeout=20)
    c = conn.cursor()
    a=['Riya', 'Vipul']
    b=[160, 173]
    p=0
    for r in b:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENTS_ VALUES (?,?);", (a[p],b[p]))     
        p=p+1
```

I Get the following error:

```
OperationalError: database is locked
```

What is this error?I know i am doing wrong, please anyone help me with a right method!!Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The "database is locked" message indicates that some other connection still has an active transaction.

Python tries to be clever and [automatically starts transactions for you](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions), so you have to ensure that you end your transactions (`conn.commit()`) when needed.